# TwinCat 3 Remote Deploy to XAR

Tags: twincat, ethercat

I'm was trying to deploy my code to a device with XAR, but I only find solutions that I've to be in the same network...
Is it possible to deploy to a device with XAR which is not in my network? I want to be at the office and try to deploy and connect to a PLC in a factory...

Answer (score 0):

As with anything networking related, this is possible but will require a great deal of assistance from your company IT Team.

All that is needed to allow for deployment from one network to another is the ADS network ports opened for communication as detailed in [Infosys](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tcremoteaccess/html/tcremoteaccess_firewall.html&id=). If you cannot gain access to the factory network for external connection then you will need to work through another solution.